# deleteMany only returns 1 value deleted in change streams

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, pusher

I have a deleteMany request but I am having a hard time in filtering my context of the deleteMany returned value. It only returns 1 value deleted from pusherjs.

Here is my change stream code and pusher code in server side;

```
if (schedules.operationType === 'delete') {
    const scheduleDetails = schedules.documentKey;              

    pusher.trigger('schedules', 'deleted', {
        _id: scheduleDetails._id,
        teamOne: scheduleDetails.teamOne,
        teamTwo: scheduleDetails.teamTwo,
        user: scheduleDetails.user,
        isDone: scheduleDetails.isDone,
        isStarted: scheduleDetails.isStarted,
        date: scheduleDetails.date,
        gameEvent: scheduleDetails.gameEvent,
    });
}
```

Here is my pusher code in client side. I am using React by the way. It is stored in my context api;

```
    ScheduleChannel.bind('deleted', ({ deletedSchedule }) => {
        console.log(deletedSchedule);
        setScheduleList(
            scheduleList.filter((schedule) => schedule._id !== deletedSchedule._id)
        );
    });
```

here is my code on request;

```
exports.deleteallmatch = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { sub } = req.user;
        const deletedMatches = await Schedule.deleteMany({ user: sub });

        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'All of your schedule is successfully deleted!',
            deletedMatches,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Something went wrong.',
        });
    }
};
```

The delete request is fine but I want to have realtime in my app. Cuz it happened that only one data is being send instead of many. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> The deleteMany() method returns an object that contains three fields:
>
> 1. n – number of matched documents
> 2. ok – 1 if the operation was successful
> 3. deletedCount – number of deleted documents

What you can do is:

1. First find all elements that match your query
2. Store them in some variable
3. Perform deleting
4. Return the stored variable

```
let deleted_items = await Schedule.find({ user: sub });
await Schedule.deleteMany({ user: sub });

return res.status(201).json({
   message: 'All of your schedule is successfully deleted!',
   deleted_items,
});
```